# Android layout using layout_weight, layout_width and maxWidth

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to get a row of text which will be something like

foofoofoo - barbarbar

but I want it to ellipse foo and bar if it won't fit on one line.
i.e. I'm trying to shorten them down.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="true"
        android:text="foofoofoofoo" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text=" - " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="true"
        android:text="barbarbarbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Bear with me this works partially.

Setting the `TextView`'s `layout_width` to be `0dip` and `layout_weight` to be `1` means they will take up 50% of the available space each.

Setting the `singleLine` to `true` and `ellipsize` to `true` means they will look like *foofoo...* if the text is larger than the container.

Therefore my outcome (if the text is longer) should be

> *foofoo.. - barbar..*

Which it is! So this works.

**Now the case I'm trying to fix is**, if the first `TextView` (id:text_1) has text that is less than the 50% given by `layout_width="0dip"` and `layout_weight="1"` I want it to `wrap_content`. Otherwise it looks like:

> *foo*        **blank space**   *- barbar..*

and I want

> *foo - barbarbar*

This is why I have changed `layout_width="wrap_content"` and added `android:maxWidth="0dip"` but this doesn't work! It seems to be ignoring me saying `wrap_content` and still giving this view 50%!

I read that you need to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for `maxWidth` to work but this had no affect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the best I could do, try changing the strings to see if it works as intended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="0,2"
    android:stretchColumns="0,2">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="foofoofoo"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the android:stretchColumns="0,2" , and it works. So far anyway! :-) thanks

Comment: @Blundell wow, I'm a bounty hunter! glad it worked and thank you for the prize.

Comment: Help's us both. I'm a benefactor :-D

Answer (score 2):

It is rather hard to tell exactly what you want, but I believe the answer is you can't do this unless you dynamically adjust your layout in code.  The reason for this is because you are asking the system to work in multiple different ways.

First, you want the views to share the space equally when the amount of text in the view is the same.

Second, you want the views to *NOT* share the space equally when there is less text in the other view.

There are multiple other cases here that can be handled any way you want.  What I'm trying to convey however, is that your asking the same layout to handle things in different ways which is why you aren't able to achieve this with a single layout.

Comment: I want to basically say maxWidth is share the space (therefore elipsing), but normally just wrap_content. So I would assume it would wrap_content unless wrap_content's dip value > 50% then it would use maxWidth (which is the 50%), no?

Comment: `unless wrap_content's dip value > 50% then it would use maxWidth`...  I'm really not sure what your trying to say.  `wrap_content` doesn't use a dip value.

Comment: Yes it doesn't but maxWidth has to interact with layout_width in some way. So I meant in the background it must calculate the layout's width and if it is > than maxWidth use maxWidth. So I'm sayin wrap_content , but if (in the background) wrap_content is > 50% use maxWidth. Is this not how it works?

Comment: I think I understand what your getting at.  The problem is the "theoretical dip value" of wrap_content changes depending on, in this case, the text in the view.  You simply can't come up with one layout that will work in all situations, like your trying to do.  See my original answer.

Comment: I don't see why layout_width="wrap_content" & maxWidth="0dip" wouldn't work :-( . In english this would be 'Wrap the content with a maxWidth of 50%'